# In VSTS, how can I access build variables in a F# task or script?

Tags: f#, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In VSTS, how can I access build variables in a F# task/script?

Stuart

Comment: Try to get the environment variable with build variable name, such as BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just access the environment variable or pass the variable value as parameter.

For example, print the value of build definition name and custom variable.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
printfn "%A" (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME"))
printfn "%A" (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVar"))
let main args = 
    printfn "%A" (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("t"))
```

Note: Tested with Execute F# Script task in [F# Helpers extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=isaacabraham.fsharp-helpers-extension).